# How to import Scalajs Facade with react-native? Error: $g.algoliasearch is not a function

Tags: scala, react-native, scala.js, react-native-ios, scalajs-react

I want to use facade Algoliasearch in my scalajs app, I imported it through sbt and but on UI I see $g.algoliasearch is not a function. I assume this is because of missing javascript libraries. I have included Algoliaseach-client-javascript dependencies in my package.json and yarn installed it.

Now I'm not sure when I use facade how I provide/link those dependencies. If someone could provide some example code that would be helpful

I am talking about any one of these facades https://github.com/DefinitelyScala/scala-js-algoliasearch

I have added jsDependencies like this

jsDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.webjars.bower" % "github-com-algolia-algoliasearch-client-javascript" % "3.18.1" / "3.18.1/reactnative.js"
)
I was hoping that above will declare something like this in my scalajs.output.ios file
var Algoliasearch = require(...) but I do not see any entry like thisand I'm still not sure how to import it to avoid following error:

$g.algoliasearch is not a function

Any help what I'm missing here please?

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1) Simply include the JavaScript dependencies as separate `<script>` tags, as normal for JavaScript and HTML. Note that these must come *before* the `<script>` tag for the Scala.js application.

2) Use the [jsDependencies](https://www.scala-js.org/doc/project/dependencies.html) mechanism to build a -jsDeps.js file, which collects all of your dependencies into one file, and include that with a `<script>` tag. (Again, before the application itself.)

Note that the facade library *can* provide the `jsDependencies`, and your application can use that, but I don't personally recommend that -- it can lead to versioning conflicts between dependencies. It tends to work best if your application simply loads the JavaScript itself.

If you are sure that your HTML file is already including the JavaScript, and you're getting this error, check to make sure that the JavaScript is being loaded before the Scala.js application runs.

Comment: Thanks Justin for coming forward to answer this question. I do not have any HTML file in my project. It's Scala.js reactive-native application. and the component I'm trying to use is https://github.com/DefinitelyScala/scala-js-algoliasearch, I added algoliasearch in my package.json and yarn added it in my node_modules and I've imported facade through package.json too but I'm not sure how to explicitly tell facade that here is your JavaScript dependencies

Comment: Ah -- I had missed that it was react-native, which I know nothing about.  But in general, keep in mind that you aren't telling the *facade* about the dependencies -- the facade just describes the JavaScript that exists outside your Scala application.  The actual question is how to load the JavaScript into your react-native application -- I suspect it needs some sort of require() command at the top level of the application description...